# Converting a double value into float explicitly and storing that in a double variable

Tags: java, casting

If I create a double variable and assign it an expression for instance (5d / 3d) and convert into float explicitly, like,

```
 double c = (float)(5d / 3d);
 System.out.println(c);
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.6666666269302368
```

It should have given precision of float datatype as float is smaller than double so double variable should have no problem in storing float value but the output is absurd. Why is it so?

Please help me in understanding the output of this code. I am unable to understand this output in the code.

Comment: Why is the output absurd?  What did you expect?

Comment: I expected that the output should be upto 7 decimal places i.e 1.6666666 which is the precision of the float datatype. As float is smaller than double therefore the double variable should not have problem to store a decimal number upto 7 places. This is what I thought but it seems the thought is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way the bit pattern is arranged when you divide five and three, it is an imprecise floating point value (it's `1.6666666` and a tiny bit). Simple as that. To demonstrate,

```
float f = (float) (5.0 / 3);
System.out.printf("%f=%s %s=%s%n", f, Float.toHexString(f), 
        (double) f, Double.toHexString(f));
System.out.printf("%s=%s %s=%s%n", f, Float.toHexString(f), 
        (double) f, Double.toHexString(f));
```

The output is

```
1.666667=0x1.aaaaaap0 1.6666666269302368=0x1.aaaaaap0
1.6666666=0x1.aaaaaap0 1.6666666269302368=0x1.aaaaaap0
```

In both cases you will notice the bit pattern is constant.

Answer (score 0):

My Java skills are very rusty, but what I think happened here is that when you cast the result of the division to a `float` you threw away half the precision.  Then, when you stored it in a `double` and passed that to `System.out.println`, `System.out.println` tried to print it to a gazillion decimal places.

But, because of the cast, those decimal places are inaccurate.  `System.out.println` has, in effect, invented them.  Try removing the cast, see what you get, or print the result as a `float`.  Doing either should give more sensible results.